# adding and combining arrays based on the element in Chemistry

Tags: php

I have created a website where it has two inputs one for the reactants and the other one is for products. After submitting the two strings, I want to output a balanced chemical equation between the reactants and the products.

For example if somebody inputs 
`H2 + O2` in the reactants and `H2O` in the products.. I want the result to be `2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O`.

I am doing this to improve my skills in using arrays. But now I stopped and do not know what to do to achieve what I want.

I have got it to return this array (for the product) :

```
[0] => 2 
[1] => 2
// [0] is the H, [1] is the O.
```

But, when I try to input something like CH6 + CH12 it will return it this way:

```
[0] => 1 
[1] => 6 
[2] => 12
// [0] is the C, [1] is the H6, [2] is the H12
```

what I really want is this :

```
[0] => 1 
[1] => 18
// [0] is the C, [1] is the H
```

my current code is this :

```
//returns H2 + H2O
$reactions = $_GET['reactions'];
//returns H2 H2O
$reactionsnospace = str_replace('+', '', $reactions);
//returns array(H2,H2O)
$reactionsarray = explode("+",$reactions);
//returns array(H2,H2,O)
$reactionsplitarray = splitAtUpperCase($reactionsnospace);

//returns the repeated number element H2 x 2 and O x 1
$reactioncountrepeatedelements = array_count_values($reactionsplitarray);
//returns the elements name with no repetition 2 and 1 ( 2 and  )
$reactionkeys = array_keys($reactioncountrepeatedelements);
foreach($reactionkeys as &$item) {
    $item = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $item);
    if(empty($item))
    {$item = "1";}
}
//returns the elements repetition number only 
$reactionvalues = array_values($reactioncountrepeatedelements);


$d = array_map(function ($a1, $a2) { return $a1 * $a2; }, $reactionkeys , $reactionvalues);
print_r($d);
```

I need suggestions to improve my code, solution to my current problem, and a method that I can use to reach my final goal of balancing a chemical equation. Is using array a good idea to do that? is there a better way?

**Read this if you do not like reading all of the above:**

I have this array:

```
Array ( [0] => C [1] => H6 [2] => C [3] => H12 [4] => Cl2)
```

what I am trying to achieve is this :

```
Array ( [0] => C2 [1] => H18 [2] => Cl2)
```

Comment: You could use a two dimensional array to represent the # of valence electrons for elements, and thus handle varying oxidation states. As far as the CH6 + CH12 example, I'm not really sure how you expect to balance these as they are invalid molecules, unless you mean Benzene (CH)6 + (some dual ring molecule) (CH)12. Even then you still only have 1 Carbon in your 1,18 result shown above.

Comment: @WebChemist I am just giving an example, I am not talking about valid and invalid chemistry here. please read the last three lines.. because this is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the last paragraph, if you just want to sum counts of the atoms, then you can use this function. The first half creates a 2 dimensional array to store each atom type and the counts, then the 2nd half sums them up and rejoins the letters to numbers.

```
function addAtoms($arr){
    $newArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $v){
        //if the entire value is alpha, assign a subscript of 1
        if(ctype_alpha($v)){
            $newArr[$v][] = 1;
        }
        //if the first 2 letters are alpha, it is an atom with 2 letters
        elseif(ctype_alpha(substr($v, 0, 2))){
            $newArr[substr($v, 0, 2)][] = substr($v, 2);
        }
        //atoms with only 1 letter like H, B, N, O, F, P, S etc
        else{
            $newArr[substr($v, 0, 1)][] = substr($v, 1);
        }
    }

    //Sum the values of the 2nd level array and concatenate to the key
    $new2 = array();
    foreach($newArr as $k => $v){
        $new2[] = $k.array_sum($v);     
    }
    return $new2;
}
```

Inputting:

```
$test = array("C", "H6" ,"C" ,"H12" ,"Cl2");
print_r(addAtoms($test));
```

Will give you the desired array of:

```
Array ( [0] => C2 [1] => H18 [2] => Cl2 )
```

**Edit**

if you had possibly more than 1 or 2 characters, you could replace the:

```
//if the first 2 letters are alpha, it is an atom with 2 letters
elseif(ctype_alpha(substr($v, 0, 2))){
    $newArr[substr($v, 0, 2)][] = substr($v, 2);
}
//atoms with only 1 letter like H, B, N, O, F, P, S etc
else{
    $newArr[substr($v, 0, 1)][] = substr($v, 1);
}
```

with the less specific:

```
else{
    $newArr[str_replace(range(0,9),'',$v)][] 
        = str_ireplace(range('a','z'),'',$v);
}
```